# Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR 2.0 and MVC 5 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, visual-studio-2013

I followed step by step this tutorial [Getting Started with SignalR 2.0 and MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5).
After build I have 1 warning and 1 error (my Visual Studio is not in english, I translated the messages):

- Conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly
  impossible to solve. These conflicts of references are listed in the
  build log when the level of detail of the log is set to detail
- The type 'SignalRChat.Startup' already defines a member called 'Configuration' with the same parameter types.

I have read the tutorial carefully several times to find my mistake without success.
Can you please help me?

I use: Visual Studio Professional 2013 v.12.0.30110.00 Update 1, .Net Framework 4.5.51641, SignalR 2.0.2.

Thanks.

**What changes should I do to be able to use it with a .Net desktop client?**

Comment: The warning is not a huge problem (although should be resolved at some point - google it for solutions). As to the error... You've got 2 methods with identical signatures. That means you've either copied/pasted code wrong or you've got a partial class (class defined in 2 different files) both of which contain the same method. Double-click the error, copy the method declaration and do a search of your solution for the same line. I haven't looked at the tutorial but you may also need to override/extend methods.

Comment: Your comment pointed me in the right direction. I did not realize that the Startup class was created automatically. The tuturial said instead of creating it. 
I've also updated all the nuget references and now works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to copy my comment from the OP...

The warning is not a huge problem (although should be resolved at some point - Google it for solutions).

As to the error... You've got 2 methods with identical signatures. That means you've either copied/pasted code wrong or you've got a partial class (class defined in 2 different files) both of which contain the same method.

Double-click the error, copy the method declaration and do a search of your solution for the same line. I haven't looked at the tutorial but you may also need to override/extend methods.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see that error if you select a different authentication provider than the one specified in the tutorial.